# Binomial random walk: Taylor series

Tags: probability, taylor-expansion

Consider the following probabilities associated with a binomial random walk:

$$ p(y',t') = \dfrac{1}{2}p(y' + \delta y, t' - \delta t) +  \dfrac{1}{2}p(y' - \delta y, t' - \delta t) $$

What's confusing me is that in my textbook, they're Taylor expanding the probabilities, for example:

$$\dfrac{1}{2}p(y' + \delta y, t' - \delta t) = p(y',t') - \dfrac{\partial p}{\partial t'} \delta t + \dfrac{\partial p}{\partial y'} \delta y + \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial ^2 p}{\partial y' ^2} \delta y^2$$

For some reason, this gives me a total mental block. I don't understand what they're doing intuitively, seeing as this is a random walk. I do understand "normal" Taylor series like for a function such as $y=\sin(x)$